# How can I get a value from Hashmap<String, Object>?

Tags: java, object, types, hashmap

I need a Map that can have values of any type. So I've tried to use *HashMap*. However, if I try to get a value from the map, the IDE says that the type doesn't match.

This is a part of my code with the matter:

```
Map<String, Object> state1 = new HashMap<>();
state1.put("location", exit1);
state1.put("direction", direction);
state1.put("number", 0);
Deque<Map> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
q.add(state1);
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

while (!q.isEmpty()) {
    Map<String, Object> state = q.poll();
    Pair location = state.get("location");
```

The variables *exit1*, *direction* are already defined before this part, so you may ignore about that. Also, you don't have to care about the code below this part.

My IDE says that the line `Map<String, Object> state = q.poll();` has incompatible types — *Pair* is required but *Object* is found. How can I make this compatible?

I am working on a problem that can run only one file, so I can't implement a new class.

Comment: `Pair location = (Pair) state.get("location");`?

Comment: You've got two generics problems: one is that your `Deque<Map>` should be a `Deque<Map<String, Object>>`; and another is in your `Map<String, Object>` the compiler won't know the precise type of the map values unless you cast them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
...
Pair location = null;
if(state.get("location") instanceof Pair){
  Pair location = (Pair)state.get("location");
}
else{
...
}
```

Comment: I will! But I have to wait to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the generic type like this:

```java
Deque<Map<String, Object>> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
```